# How to pass Objective-C class instance variable to another class instance variable without object reference?

Tags: objective-c

I have Three class A ,B and C.

```
@interface ClassA

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *classCArray;

@end

@implementation ClassA 
...
@end

@interface ClassB

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *classCArray;

@end

@implementation ClassB
...
@end

@interface ClassC

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation ClassC
...
@end
```

Then I create instance "a" of Class A, set "a" variable classCArray ,and pass a.classArray to "b"(instance of ClassB).

```
ClassA *a = [ClassA alloc] init];
ClassC *cInClassA = [ClassC alloc] init];
cInClassA.name = @"jack";
[a.classCArray addObject:c];

ClassB *b = [ClassB alloc] init];
b.classCArray = a.classCArray;
ClassC *cInClassB = b.classCArray[0];
cInClassB.name = @"Bob";
```

After above code , cInClassA.name changed.(eauqls "Bob") I don't hope this happen. How I can do ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that assignment copies objects, it does not. A variable, such as your `a`, can only ever store a *reference* to an object and assignment copies the reference.

Your code creates 4 objects: instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` referenced by `a` and `b` respectively; a single instance of `NSMutableArray` referenced by both `a.classCArray` and `b.classCArray`; and a single instance of `ClassC` referenced by the mutable array and variables `cInClassA` and `cInClassB`.

If you wish to create a copy of an object use the method `copy`, or for a mutable copy of a mutable object use `mutableCopy`.

HTH

Comment: Thank you.I implemented `- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;`for ClassC(this is a NSCopying method in cocoa),then use [myObject copy],it worked!.